# iptables NAT is Policy Accept a security hole?

Tags: linux, security, iptables, firewall, nat

im hardening my vps-server and
and I saw recently that all policies are open (**ACCEPT**) at Nat Table. Im searching internet and found nothing about securing nat table. Is that a security hole or not ?  Here the OUTPUT:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 21038 packets, 1097K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                 

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 9 packets, 1088 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 187 packets, 14396 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                 

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 48 packets, 3767 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                 
  523  140K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

For every help im thanksfull

kind regards blackbeard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is perfectly fine to use an ACCEPT policy for the *nat* table. Using a DROP policy would be an anomaly.

A packet traverses various chains in various tables following this schematic:

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking]

Being accepted, just means the packet gets an other chance of being accepted or dropped in the next round (ie: the next chain and its rules to receive this packet). Being dropped has an instant effect: the packet disappears and no other rule is processed for this packet. So as the packet traverses the various chains in the various tables, there's plenty of places it can be dropped. One DROP anywhere will remove the packet. An additional ACCEPT (eg: if NAT is never used, there's no *nat* table created) will not change this result.

As the *nat* table is intended to do NAT and not to filter traffic (for this there's a dedicated table: *filter*), there's no reason to have NAT ever drop traffic. It's still technically possible to do it, but anyway you have also to consider that NAT is not handled like other tables because it is really part of *conntrack*: only the first packet of each new flow are seen in *iptables*' *nat* table, in order to establish NAT rules for the flow. Others won't, their handling is done directly by *conntrack* which follows the NAT rules (included in the relevant *conntrack* table that can be consulted with the [`conntrack`](https://manpages.debian.org/conntrack/conntrack.8) command).

So in short, you should never DROP in the *nat* table: you should ACCEPT or RETURN to create exceptions to following rules actually doing NAT (thus leaving the packet untouched so it will continue to the next round), or use the various NAT targets available (eg: DNAT, REDIRECT, SNAT, MASQUERADE ...) to establish the NAT rules for this flow (which will also have the packet continue to the next round). Leave the DROP default policy to chains in the *filter* table. The *mangle* table can also be used to drop traffic, but it's usually not configured with a default DROP policy either for its chains. As for the little known *security* table I wouldn't know, it's rarely used, so rarely existing.